# How to install conky-manager on Lubuntu 18.04?

Tags: lubuntu, 18.04, conky

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install conky-manager
sudo apt-get install selene
```

It does not work on Lubuntu 18.04. How to install it?

Comment: What exactly does not work? It would be helpful if you posted the error message.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! The error message is here.    --------------------                                 $ sudo apt-get install conky-manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package conky-manager

Comment: Please add the error message directly to your question by editing it, instead of putting it into the comments here, so it is better visible directly for other users. You might also want to consider to remove the line `sudo apt-get install selene` from your question, since it appears that this line is not related to the problem you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

The package can't be located, because you are adding the wrong `ppa` for your OS version to install `conky-manager`.

`conky-manager` in `ppa:teejee2008/ppa` is only maintained up to and including Ubuntu 16.04, so most of the tutorials that can be found around the internet are outdated as of now.

From Ubuntu 17.10 onwards (so also for Lubuntu 17.10 onwards), you have to use `ppa:tomtomtom/conky-manager` instead. But as always, beware if you trust an unknown `ppa`.

Comment: Thank you!     But I failed.  -----Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 conky-manager : Depends: realpath but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @bayou Ok, what have you tried to resolve the `held broken packages` error? There is quite a bit of information available regarding this problem, you may start reading [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages). If nothing works for you, you should open another question including what you've tried, to keep this one here focused on the original problem.

Comment: Thank you for the advice,@Wanderer.But before reading your message,I formated the partition this early morning.